# What's the best practice in cocos2d to redirect an animating sprite?

Tags: animation, cocos2d-iphone, sprite, action

I am making a game where 'defending' sprites need to animate towards 'attacking' sprites. 
But for example an attacker might change course to attack something else, mid animation. What's the best way to manage animations, and destinations? I believe I must remove any action on a sprite before adding a new one. Perhaps I need to use the shared action manager or something??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just stop the existing actions, and add the new animation to the sprite.